# Execution order in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I'm reading [a documentation for postgreSQL SELECT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html) as I want to find the order in which SQL statements in SELECT are processed.

In the documentation it says:

> SELECT retrieves rows from zero or more tables. The general processing of SELECT is as follows: (...)
>
> 6. (...) SELECT DISTINCT ON eliminates rows that match on all the specified expressions. (...)
>
> 8. If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the returned rows are sorted in the specified order. (...)

It further says (in [DISTINCT clause description](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)):

> The DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as
>   for ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is
>   unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row
>   appears first. (...)
>
> The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s). The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within each DISTINCT ON group.

My natural expectation is that ORDER BY should modify the result of DISTINCT ON and since DISTINCT ON may (and probably will) give unpredictable results, it is - simply put - useless, if not preceded with another SELECT query.

**What is the actual execution order of statements in SELECT statement?

*In particular*: why is ORDER BY processed before DISTINCT ON?**

---

I'm not an experienced user of postgreSQL and SQL thus I don't know if I'm asking the right question ([XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). If you think this question should be "*How exactly does DISTINCT ON work?*" or maybe even "*Does the placement of keywords in SELECT statement matter?*" or anything else, please edit the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First "order of processing" is a bit misleading in SQL.  The statements are *compiled* before execution.  The actual execution might look very different from the SQL itself (in fact, the execution is represented as a DAG -- directed acyclic graph -- which looks nothing like `SELECT` syntax).

`DISTINCT ON` is a Postgres extension.  It is quite handy -- letting you get one row per value in the parentheses.  And, you can control which row.

Let's say you have data like this:

```
a    b    c
A1   3    1
A1   2    2
A1   4    3
A2   6    4
A2   1    5
```

You use `distinct on` when you want to specify that you want *one* row per value.  And, it let's you specify the value that you want.  For instance, to get the row with the lowest value of `b` for each `a`:

```
select distinct on (a) a, b, c
from t
order by a, b asc;
```

To get the row with the highest value of `b` for each `a`:

```
select distinct on (a) a, b, c
from t
order by a, b desc;
```

The expressions in the parentheses need to match the expressions the leading expressions in the `order by`.

You are not going to get a feel for how this works by reading the documentation.  You need to use it.

This functionality can be replaced by a subquery with `row_number()` and a `where` clause in the outer query.  This is probably why other databases have not adapted similar functionality.

Comment: I've seen it in use. I was looking for many examples for several hours now and I think I understand how it works. I just don't get why postgreSQL kind of 'jumps' from DISTINCT ON to ORDER BY and uses it's resulting table. If it does it for these two, how does one know it doesn't for other keywords?
In many languages you can put parentheses to make it clear what is done first. In case of SQL I struggle with understanding what is the current 'resulting' table in every step.

Comment: @AkaZecik: Postgres **first** sorts the rows based on the `order by`, **then** applies the `distinct on ()`

Comment: @AkaZecik Postgres  'jumps' from DISTINCT ON to ORDER BY because it's exactly what you told it to do by specifying both clauses in the statement: to apply DISTINCT with regard to ORDER BY.