# Distinct on column using custom order

Tags: database, postgresql, distinct, database-view

I have a DB view.

At this point it returns rows which can have duplicate entries in `id` column.
I would like to do the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) USING DESCRIBED BELOW RULE -- of course it is not valid sql
  id
  type
```

`type` column can have 3 values:

- `x`
- `y`
- `z`

If there are rows with identical `id` but different `type`, the rule for `DISTINCT` is as follows:

- select row with type `x` first
- select row with type `y` if no `x`
- select row with type `z` if no `x` and no `y`

So if I have 3 rows:

```
id    type
1     'y'
1     'x'
2     'z'
```

The expected result will be

```
id    type
1     'x'
2     'z'
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put the hierarchy in a `CASE` expression in `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) * 
FROM   ( VALUES (1, 'y'), 
                (1, 'x'), 
                (2, 'z') ) s(id, type) 
ORDER  BY id, 
          CASE type 
            WHEN 'x' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'y' THEN 2 
            WHEN 'z' THEN 3 
          END;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=426e1f0fb9c94d3af9f69681c317686b)

Comment: I don't understand how it work though, is `ORDER BY` gets "triggered" before `DISTINCT`? So it first get duplicate rows, order them by `type` and then `DISTINCT` just picks the first one?

Comment: Could you please answer my question?

Comment: @Andrey Deineko : This should answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46142892

Answer (score 1):

If your values are alphabetically ordered in real (as in your example) it would be quiet simple - you only have to order the values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
    id,
    type
FROM mytable m
ORDER BY id, type
```

---

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b6c41ecd9fac1a66ac987979ca899615)

If not you'll need a table were the ranked values and their ranked order are stored. Or you simulate it with a subquery as I did:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
    id,
    type
FROM mytable m
JOIN (VALUES (1, 'x'), (2, 'y'), (3, 'z')) AS r (rank_id,value)
ON r.value = m.type
ORDER BY id, r.rank_id
```

---

If your type data is really fixed you could think about an [enum type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html) which is an ordered type by default. The query would look like the first above:

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2142fa02b091d61d99a2d4916698af32)

But notice that changing enums (adding, deleting, rearranging values) could be very hard. So it is only recommended if the type is really fixed. Otherwise take a separate table with foreign keys which takes you to back to the second part.

Comment: I liked the idea with ranked table but somehow it didn't work. Tough the `CASE` option suggested by @Kaushik Nayak worked. As to enum: yea, I try to avoid enums

Comment: Why didn't it work? Here's a sample fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c652972d128da4fb4c1027431bfe0651